# Simulink - How to create independent custom blocks using callback functions

Tags: matlab, callback, simulink

I am currently coding a new library with several models in it (I am used to Matlab, but not to Simulink). I am able to create a model with block parameters, let's say parameter 'p', and a callback function (initfct) which uses this parameter to compute specific values used inside my model (let say a simple gain K=K(p)).

My problem is that my parameter 'p' and 'K' are available directly on the workspace, what I don't want to. Moreover, if I use twice or more this model in a system, the two models share always the same 'K', which also I don't want to.

So how I can make these variables 'p' and 'K' independent when I use my custom model several time, and to prevent these variables to be viewed in the workspace ?

Should I use "Reference models", but I am not familiar with this feature ... ?

Thanks for you answer, 
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Within a callback, `gcb` returns the path to the block which currently executes the callback. Having the path, you can use `get_param` to access the parameters.

Just for demonstation purposes, insert the following to the MoveFcn of a delay block:

```
set_param(gcb,'DelayLength',num2str(randi(10)))
```

It will randomly change the delay whenever the block is moved.

I am not sure if my answer explains everything you need. It might be that you also need a Mask. If you think this answer is incomplete, please update your question and include a small example model demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, with your help I was able to solve the problem.

To be more specific if someone else has the same problem : you need in your mask to declare also internal variables used by the callback function. Unchecked the relevant options so that they not appear as standard input parameters of your model.

My problem was also to use num2str instead of mat2str (when the gain was a matrix acting on multiple inputs).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.